# Yii widgets.TbThumbnails Pagination

Tags: yii, pagination, thumbnails

I am using this 'widgets.TbThumbnails' from bootstrap to show the list of items as thumbnails. It shows first 10 items in one page and another 10 items on the other page. further it shows page navigator button at the bottom of the page. I tried to show all the items in a single page, but couldn't. If anyone know please help me to fix this. here is my code for thumbnail view

```
<?php  $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Symptoms');
$this->widget('ext.bootstrap.widgets.TbThumbnails',
array(            
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'template' => "{items}\n{pager}",
    'itemView' => '_thumb',
    //'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:975px;','height:1020px'),
    )       
  );
  ?>
```

Comment: Hi Rafay Zia Mir I already tried in this way and got an error "Unexpected array" it doesn't work for me

Comment: can you please add full error in your question so it may be more clear

Comment: Yes I have corrected the code there a comma has to come in between the Model and array  Now it works fine Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that is due to the fact that `dataProvider` uses default settings for pagination.
`Cpagination` has a property named `pageSize` which refers to the the number of items per page. By default this is set to `10` thats why you can see 10 items per page.

Here is [Official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#pageSize-detail).

You can do like this:

```
<?php
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Symptoms', array(
        'pagination'=>false
    ));          

    $this->widget('ext.bootstrap.widgets.TbThumbnails', array(            
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,           
        'itemView' => '_thumb',            
        )       
    );
?>
```